# C# for loop increment by 2 trouble

Tags: c#-4.0

This algorithm is about to store strings from Array A to Array B by storing "A", "B" to Index 8 and Index 9
I really initiate to make the array size of B to be 10 because later I will put some other things there.

My partial code:

```
string[] A = new string[]{"A","B"}
string[] B = new string[10]; 
int count;

for(count = 0; count < A.length; count++)
{
      B[count] = A[count]
}
```

Comment: Imagine how you can increment something by 2? Do you know what mean `count++`?

Comment: `*` does multiplication in C#.

Comment: `count += 2` the update side of a for loop in C# needs to use compound assignment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So you want to increment every index with 2:

```
string[] A = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
string[] B = new string[A.Length + 2];
for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    B[i + 2] = A[i];
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/8brFRU)

```
Index: 0 Value: 
Index: 1 Value: 
Index: 2 Value: A
Index: 3 Value: B
Index: 4 Value: C
Index: 5 Value: D
```

**Edit**: So you want to start with index 0 in B and always leave a gap?

```
string[] A = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
string[] B = new string[A.Length * 2 + 2]; // you wanted to add something other as well
for (int i = 0; i/2 < A.Length; i+=2)
{
    B[i] = A[i / 2];
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/fZy4yz)

```
Index: 0 Value: A
Index: 1 Value: 
Index: 2 Value: B
Index: 3 Value: 
Index: 4 Value: C
Index: 5 Value: 
Index: 6 Value: D
Index: 7 Value: 
Index: 8 Value: 
Index: 9 Value:
```

**Update** " Is there any alternative coding aside from this?"

You can use Linq, although it would be less readable and efficient than a simple loop:

```
String[] Bs = Enumerable.Range(0, A.Length * 2 + 2) // since you want two empty places at the end
 .Select((s, i) => i % 2 == 0 && i / 2 < A.Length ? A[i / 2] : null)
 .ToArray();
```

Final **Update** according to your last comment(*start with index 1 in B*):

```
for (int i = 1; (i-1) / 2 < A.Length; i += 2)
{
    B[i] = A[(i-1) / 2];
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/OWkZyz)

```
Index: 0 Value: 
Index: 1 Value: A
Index: 2 Value: 
Index: 3 Value: B
Index: 4 Value: 
Index: 5 Value: C
Index: 6 Value: 
Index: 7 Value: D
Index: 8 Value: 
Index: 9 Value
```

Comment: @ChrisAplaon: I've edited my answer. You should include the desired output into your question as well.

Comment: yes sir, Is there any alternative coding aside from this? For a beginner like me to understand.

Comment: @ChrisAplaon: For the sake of completeness, added the (not appropriate) Linq approach.

Comment: woah, I saw this kind of coding in other questions in the site but I still having a hard time to comprehend with it. By the way Sir, thank you really much. The code works even I trace it manually.

Comment: Sir , I would like to add another problem. Can?

Comment: @ChrisAplaon: Yes, go ahead! Note that if the other problem is not related to this, you should better ask a another question. Remember to accept the best answer.

Comment: I'll, edit the demo again to show my expression, hte new problem is, the storing of the string will start in Index 1 in array B.

Comment: @ChrisAplaon: I've already provided an answer(edited it) before you've posted the link to ideone. My approach now starts with index 1 as in your demo. Is this not desired/correct?

Comment: yes, that is it sir.

about 2.
Mr. Kovalenko, got also the correct answer. 

the only difference is, he focus to add some code in Array B
in B[i*2]

and also your code is also correct , but you focus in Array A,
in A[i/2] which also correct.

I rate him also as correct because my intuition in the first place was to change something in Array B which give me a hard time to think and test.

Comment: ok sir, I would like to another problem, I will edit the demo.

Comment: @ChrisAplaon: You should edit your question instead of my answer (but keep what you have already). But since i've seen what you've tried to edit, what is the rule for adding `"A","B"` in the last two indices of the array? Do you want to take the first two and put it in the last two slots? And why is the rest of the array empty, is that desired? [ As a **rule of thumb**: don't ask more than one question in a question on Stackoverflow ;) ]

Comment: The comments are not a good place for long discussions, please move to the chat if you want to continue!

Comment: @markus-tharkun: He cannot yet use the chat (20 rep minimum).

Comment: @TimScheltmer: Ok sir. Yes, I want to put the string "A" and "B" to the last array slots in B. Index 8:["A"] and Index 9 :["B"]. Sorry late reply.

Comment: @ChrisAplaon: But what's the rule for it? I assume that it's not as simple as: `B[8]="A";B[9]="B";`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, for riffle shuffle theory

Comment: @ChrisAplaon:  _Shuffle/Riffle_ does not help to understand. You should consider to ask a new qustion since a question on Stackoverflow normally covers just one issue. Always think of your question as a single unit that helps future people to solve a similar issue.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ok sir. If I follow the code you gave. It will be just a hard code.

Answer (score 2):

Another attempt to guess what you want:

```
string[] A = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
string[] B = new string[A.Length * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    B[i*2] = A[i];
}
```