# Optimize triplet summation in C++

Tags: c++, sum, triplet

### Problem

I need to compute a function of an array of integers. For every three-element subset (or triplet) of the array, I need to compute the term floor((sum of triplet)/(product of triplet)). Then I need to return the sum of all such terms.

### Example

Input (length; array):

```
5
1 2 1 7 3
```

Output:

```
6
```

### Explanation

The following triplets exist in the given array:

> 1 2 1
>
> 1 2 7
>
> 1 2 3
>
> 1 1 7
>
> 1 1 3
>
> 1 7 3
>
> 2 1 7
>
> 2 1 3
>
> 2 7 3
>
> 1 7 3

Considering these triplets from the sample input:

1 2 1 contributes 2, because floor((1+2+1)/(1*2*1)) = floor(4/2) = 2

1 2 3 contributes 1

1 1 7 contributes 1

1 1 3 contributes 1

2 1 3 contributes 1

All other triplets contribute 0 to the sum.

Hence the answer is (2+1+1+1+1)=6.

### My Solution

What I tried is complexity O(n^3). Code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long t,n[300005],sum=0,mul=1,i,j,k,res=0;
    cin >> t;

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        cin >>n[i];


    for(i=0;i<t-2;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<t-1;j++)
    for(k=j+1;k<t;k++)
    {
        sum = n[i]+n[j]+n[k];
        mul = n[i]*n[j]*n[k];
        res += floor(sum/mul);
    }

    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any hint of better optimization?

Comment: If you want to improve working code better ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what about incrementing your i by 3 steps each time? you would only need one for loop. Something like this should work http://stackoverflow.com/a/14413535/4511978

Answer (score 0):

While still O(n^3), you could save some operations by caching the redundant calculations between `n[i]` and `n[j]` as you iterate over `n[k]`.

For example:

```
long sum_ij,mul_ij;

for(i=0;i<t-2;i++) {
  for(j=i+1;j<t-1;j++) {

    sum_ij = n[i]+n[j];
    mul_ij = n[i]*n[j];

    for(k=j+1;k<t;k++)
    {
       sum = sum_ij+n[k];
       mul = mul_ij*n[k];
       res += floor(sum/mul);
    }
  }
}
```